# Get an Item of a Custom View

Tags: android

Hellow guys,
I have an android resource layout file *view_notification_badge.xml* as below

```
`<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_notify_50" />

    <com.adalipa.smartcard.api.payment.font.RobotoTextView
        android:id="@+id/badgecount"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle.RaisedEmpty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:minWidth="112dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FF3D00"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="PrivateResource" />
</FrameLayout>`
```

and i have my MainActivity.java method that sets the badge on the BottomNavigationView as below

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
                BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(2);
                notificationBadge = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.view_notification_badge, menuView, false);

                itemView.addView(notificationBadge);
```

My issue is how can i get the RobotoTextView item badgecount in XML fileso that  so that i can set text to it using my my Java code?. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the id of the `TextView`, you can use [View.findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) on the inflated `View`:

```
TextView tvCount = notificationBadge.findViewById(R.id.badgecount);
```

Comment: Throws Exception that the TextView Not found!

Comment: @Tata Nyerere - then maybe you have a typo somewhere? My answer is about how to use the method on a View ( not an Activity, because it looks like that's what was missing). Please refer to the linked documentation and adapt it to your situation.